# How to find sum of numpy array columns

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

So I want to find the sum of each list in a numpy array and store it in separate variables. I have tried using a nested for loop but found out that I can't loop through a numpy array's index. I found the numpy.sum function but i'm not sure how I would implement it in this case.

This is my numpy array:

[['2659' '2623.5' '2749.5' '2826.5' '2775' '2795' '2810' '2845' '2827'
  '2847' '2854' '2897.5' '2905' '2925' '2902.5' '2869.5']

['3342.5' '3386' '3385' '3353' '3300' '3190' '3087.5' '3092' '3170'
  '3225' '3340' '3315' '3396' '3470' '3480' '3380']

['2996' '2989' '2953' '2950' '2884.5' '2829' '2785' '2908' '2850' '2761'
  '2997.5' '3020' '2952' '2997.5' '2952' '2923.5']

['2804.5' '2850.5' '2850' '2850' '2867' '2940' '2905' '2945' '2938'
  '2860' '2884' '2946' '2938' '2986.5' '2931.5' '3032.5']

['2800' '3074' '2950' '2850' '2850' '2875' '2757' '2716' '2738.5' '2696'
  '2809' '2891' '3000' '2960' '2950' '2831']

['3215' '3250' '3290' '3260' '3200' '3350' '3507.5' '3301' '3276' '3320'
  '3550' '3500' '3530' '3498.5' '3505' '3605']

['2597.5' '2649' '2625.5' '2890' '3325' '3200' '3010' '2850' '2800'
  '2745' '2695' '2695' '2850' '2850' '2860' '2695']

['2783.5' '2800' '2812' '2809' '2813.5' '2817' '2815' '2849' '2850'
  '2927' '2810' '2890' '2910' '2996' '2950' '2897']

['2350' '2350' '2350' '2475' '2400' '2495' '2567.5' '2525' '2400' '2350'
  '2487.5' '2395' '2397.5' '2450' '2562.5' '2500']

['3152.5' '3015' '3060' '3027.5' '2950' '3000' '3002.5' '3022.5' '2865'
  '2850' '2825' '2895' '3020' '3022.5' '3110' '3185']

['3337' '3500' '3484' '3519' '3393.5' '3295' '3062.5' '3057' '3123.5'
  '3103' '3079' '3216' '3221' '3200' '3214' '3405.5']

['3180' '3325' '3495' '3488.5' '3271.5' '3216' '3235' '3216' '3300'
  '3405' '3388.5' '3600' '3915' '3629.5' '3541' '3405']

['2800' '3049' '3000' '3032' '2995' '2987.5' '2850' '3000' '3000' '2895'
  '2992.5' '3080' '3378.5' '3094.5' '3056' '3150']

['2871.5' '2850' '2751' '2710' '2800' '2875' '2845' '2700' '2784.5'
  '2749' '2800' '2875' '2905' '3028' '3100' '3100']

['3552.5' '3550' '3540' '3510' '3495' '3510' '3512.5' '3525' '3300'
  '3270' '3250' '3182.5' '3200' '3200' '3250' '3200']

['3397.5' '3389' '3450' '3400' '3300' '3500' '3495' '3497.5' '3395'
  '3595' '3350' '3350' '3425' '3399.5' '3364.5' '3325.5']

['3550' '3472' '3493' '3344.5' '3332' '3251' '3270.5' '3358' '3370.5'
  '3465.5' '3495' '3495' '3500' '3495' '3458' '3550']

['2805' '2833' '2900' '2930' '2795' '2800' '2890' '2949' '2800' '2850'
  '2839' '2900' '2850' '2995' '3087.5' '2950.5']

['3495' '3530' '3610' '4200' '3990' '3925' '4000' '3785' '3792.5' '3525'
  '3495' '3850' '3900' '4137.5' '4000' '4200']

['3545' '3355' '3305' '3143' '3220' '3200' '3180' '3639' '3260' '3265'
  '3510' '3575' '3695' '3482.5' '3600' '3292.5']

['2995' '3180' '3225' '3204' '3219' '3109' '2998.5' '2995' '3200'
  '3193.5' '3161' '3195' '3200' '3338.5' '3200' '3176']

['3599' '3641' '3796' '3650' '3552.5' '3570' '3535' '3465' '3400' '3316'
  '3640' '3770' '3440' '3790' '3815' '3692.5']

['3500' '3509.5' '3519' '3717.5' '3495' '3435' '3285' '3162.5' '3425'
  '3375' '3410' '3472.5' '3600' '3980' '3657.5' '3650']

['3773' '3696' '3708' '3778' '3689' '3625' '3516' '3518.5' '3647' '3596'
  '3685' '3945' '3811' '3848' '3699' '4021.5']]

For example how do I find the sum of the first index of the array and store it in a variable:

['2659' '2623.5' '2749.5' '2826.5' '2775' '2795' '2810' '2845' '2827'
  '2847' '2854' '2897.5' '2905' '2925' '2902.5' '2869.5']

and so on through the whole array. I should end up with 24 different sums.

Comment: If you can just give me the part of the code where you declare the array, I can try to help you. It just I don't want to build your array to test my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For numpy sum(), you can pass numpy sum an array and it will give you back the sum of that array. But your array is a nested array and you want a separate sum of each index, thus just pass numpy sum the second level array. Store the sum in another array. For storing sum you can simply append to the sum list or you can do exactly like the below.

```
import numpy as np
arrayNum = np.array([[2659,2623.5,2749.5],[12,45,89],[123,478,910]])

sumArr = [None] * len(arrayNum)

for i in range(0, len(arrayNum)):
    sumArr[i] = np.sum(arrayNum[i])

print(sumArr)
```